# delete multiple lines from cursor position in vi editor

Tags: unix

I need to delete multiple lines(ex:45 lines) from the cursor position(ex: from line 10). for example I am at line 360 and trying to delete 45 lines from that.

so I have tried following command:

```
:45dd
```

but it was not working.please help me from this.

Comment: This isn't a suitable question for SO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use in `commad mode` `45dd`

Comment: i have tried this but it is deleting 45th line in that file (i have done :45d).

Comment: In command mode 45dd delete current line to 45 line surly ,I think you tried in ex mode ,in ex mode you can use `:.,45d` so `.` means current line to 45 th line

Comment: You can read this ,it is useful for you http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LinuxTutorialAdvanced_vi.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use like this also in ex mode

```
:.,45d

.  --  Current position of the cursor

to

45 lines delete (d)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try without colon. Just 45dd
If you do :45 you go to line 45... and if you add a d you delete that line.